# htaccess RewriteRule special characters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this line of code:

```
RewriteRule ^account/?edit=([A-Za-z]+)$ /?goTo=account&act=edit_$1 [L,NC]
```

When I go to `mysite.com/account/?edit=username` it is supposed to refer to `mysite.com?goTo=account&act=edit_username` but it **gives me error 404**

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: RewriteRule works on the _path_ component of the URL only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING using `RewriteRule`. That requires a `RewriteCond` like this:

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)edit=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^account/?$ /?goTo=account&act=edit_%1#something [L,NC,NE,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: And if I needed an url like `mysite.com?goTo=account&act=edit_username#something` What to I need to add?